# N_RESIZE_CURSOR vs. S_RESIZE_CURSOR in Java

Tags: java

I've been using:

```java
Cursor.N_RESIZE_CURSOR
Cursor.S_RESIZE_CURSOR
Cursor.W_RESIZE_CURSOR
Cursor.E_RESIZE_CURSOR
```

and all this time I've been wondering, is there any difference between `N` and `S`, also `W` and `E`?

I've tried using only `N` and `W` (without `S` and `E`) and I felt no difference; because the cursor of `N` is the same as `S`, and `W` is the same as `E`.
However, there's gotta be reason(s) why the developer(s) make them that way (or at least I think so). Is it just to make the list complete (i.e., only `N` and `W` will not make the whole four directions completely listed)?

So out of curiosity during my tea time, I want to ask: does anybody know any difference of `N` and `S`, also `W` and `E` that I possibly don't know yet?

*note: I've tried to google it, but still haven't got my answer*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the original developers of the API were taking into account the possibility of differences between platforms and how different platforms provide this functionality.

Where there is no difference, then the `N`/`S` and `E`/`W` constants would make to the same thing.

Comment: And it's not just a theoretical possibility:  they actually *are* different in some environments, such as GNOME.